# MATLAB: a faster way to dilate or thicken a region of interest in a binary image

Tags: performance, matlab, binary

I have a region of interest in a binary image. I am trying to grow that region of interest in a quick way. I can use `imdilate(bwimage,se);` or `bwmorph(bwimage,'thicken')` which is a little faster but still not fast enough. Any suggestions? It doesn't need to be perfect but it needs to be fast-a large version of the region of interest centered at the same location.

Thanks

Comment: How big is your image? What is "fast enough"?

Comment: The image is about 1500x300 pixels, I don't have a good target speed...but I'm already using bwconncomp and region props which gives me a pixel index list and a centroid..there's got to be some non-convolving way to magnify the region specified in the pixel index list over that centroid?

Comment: How big is the roi? If you've got the bounding box, you can dilate just that area.